# what is standard user mouse speed range, on which GUI web-developer can rely?

Tags: browser, mouse, mouseevent

As you know, browsers generate events depending on mouse speed (sometimes failing to generate, if mouse speed is too high).
Are there any research - on which speed should any application be optimized and on which - should not?